# ROW_NUMBER() over groups by condition

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, window-functions

suppose we have a DataFrame with column "event":

```
events
A
b
c
d
e
A
b
c
d
A
f
```

I want to get WindowGroups or just new column with row_number() over such split

```
events
A
b
c
d
e
f
g
----- split here ---
A
b
c
d
----- split here ---
A
f
```

So I want to put all rows between to "A" in "events" column to one group. How to do it? I feel like it can be done with Window functions.

Comment: Does your table have a column to sort events?

Comment: @etsuhisa yes, I do. In the example I've put it already sorted but initially they are not.

Comment: Does it mean the capital "A" is a chunk of data that you want to process separately until next "A" occurs?

Comment: @AlexeyNovakov yes

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I got a solution by myself. Here it is:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
 val windowIndex = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("time")

val result = eventWithTime
  .withColumn("groupId",
    when($"events" === "A", row_number over windowIndex).otherwise(null))
  .withColumn("groupId", last("groupId", ignoreNulls = true) over windowIndex)
  .filter($"groupId".isNotNull)
```

(I use column "time" just to order events like in example)

The idea here is to find all "events" with "A" and mark them with unique id. I did it using `row_number` and `Window.partitionBy()` functions. (Maybe it is would be better to use `monotonically_increasing_id` but I have a lot of data and there are some assumptions for correct work of `monotonically_increasing_id`). After that, I used function `last` with same window. Important thing here is to set ignoreNulls to "true". In that way all nulls will be filled with first non-null value before current row. Then I just drop first rows before first "A" because they are still nulls.

Ex.:

1. Before any operations

```
events
A
b
c
d
e
A
b
c
d
A
f
```

2. Assign unique id to all "A"s (otherwise null)

```
events | groupId
A      | 1
b      | null
c      | null
d      | null
e      | null
A      | 2
b      | null
c      | null
d      | null
A      | 3
f      | null
```

3. Fill nulls using last non-null value

```
events | groupId
A      | 1
b      | 1
c      | 1
d      | 1
e      | 1
A      | 2
b      | 2
c      | 2
d      | 2
A      | 3
f      | 3
```

Now we can just `groupBy` or `partitionBy` by groupId and do what we want.

Comment: Nice solution! Since operation is sequential I would approach it in Scala using fs2 or akka-streams within a single JVM.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE  #tbl(event nvarchar(5))
insert into #tbl (event)values('A'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('e'),('A'),('b'),('c'), 
('d'),('A'),('f')    
CREATE TABLE #EventDetails(event nvarchar(5),groupId int)    
DECLARE @event_name varchar(20),@group_id int=0    



DECLARE event_cursor CURSOR FOR     
SELECT event
FROM #tbl     
  
OPEN event_cursor      
FETCH NEXT FROM event_cursor     
INTO @event_name    
   
  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0    
BEGIN    
    if(@event_name ='a')
    begin
        set @group_id  = @group_id+1        
        insert into #EventDetails (event ,groupId)  
        values (@event_name,@group_id)
    end
    else
    begin
        insert into #EventDetails (event ,groupId)  
        values (@event_name,@group_id)
    end
  
      
FETCH NEXT FROM event_cursor     
INTO @event_name      
END     
CLOSE event_cursor;    
DEALLOCATE event_cursor;    


select * from #EventDetails

drop table #EventDetails
drop table #tbl

=====================
Result
=====================
event   groupId
A         1
b         1
c         1
d         1
e         1
A         2
b         2
c         2
d         2
A         3
f         3
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).